# Calling onOK from onKeyPress in Ant Design Modal in React

Tags: reactjs, antd

Calling myMethod() directly in onKeyPress enables it to be called multiple times on multiple key presses. How to call onOK inside onKeyPress to enable calling myMethod only once?

```
   <Modal 
      onOk={myMethod}>
      <Form layout="vertical">
        <FormItem label="">          
            <Input onKeyPress={(event) => {
              if (event.key === "Enter") {
                onOk();
              }
            }}/>
          }
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
   </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

onOk={ () => myMethod () }

Try this.